# Get count before updating the Oracle table in Java

Tags: java, oracle, count

I have a dropdown list that holds all the columns name from the table. When the user selects a certain column name and enters a specific value to search for along with two different dates, I get that information and update the table as shown below.

But before updating I want to prompt a dialog box asking the user "This many rows will be updated, do you want to do this?". Can I modify something in this code to get that count before it's updated or is there a better way to do this?

```
sql.append(" UPDATE Table_jack ");
sql.append(" set date = to_date('" + this.getNewDate() + "','MM/DD/YYYY')");
if ((this.getSelectedDDL() != null)&& (this.getSelectedDDL().equals("1"))){
    sql.append("  where id_nbr =" + this.getValue() + "'");
    sql.append("  and date between to_date('" + this.getDateFrom() + "','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('" + this.getDateTo() + "','MM/DD/YYYY')");
}

if ((this.getSelectedDDL() != null)&& (this.getSelectedDDL().equals("2"))){
    sql.append("  where name =" + this.getValue() + "'");
    sql.append("  and date between to_date('" + this.getDateFrom() + "','MM/DD/YYYY') and to_date('" + this.getDateTo() + "','MM/DD/YYYY')");
}

ResultSet rset =  db.executeQuery(sql.toString(),true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than trying to get a count before you issue the update, get a count of the number of rows actually updated and display that to the user before issuing the `COMMIT` (or `ROLLBACK`).

The `Statement.executeUpdate` method returns the number of rows that the `UPDATE` statement modified. If you used that rather than `executeQuery`, you could get a row count from the `UPDATE` statement.  You could then present that to the user before ending the transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to build and run a separate `select count(*)` query to get the number of rows to be updated.  There is also the chance that the data could change between the time you do your `select count(*)` and update the table.  If that is an issue, you would need to lock the table for the duration of your queries.